# Как сделать autocomplete в админке по GenericForeignKey

Tags: django, django-admin

Привет! Есть модель `Menu` которая содержит пункты меню `MenuItem`, пункты меню составляются из полей `name` (название пункта меню) и `slug` (ссылка пункта меню) из моделей `Page`, `Article` и других моделей в будущем. Решил попробовать `GenericForeignKey`, ограничил выбор двумя нужными мне моделями.

Проблема в том, что при создании пунктов меню в админке, можно выбрать тип модели и вбивать вручную `pk` объекта.
[image: Добавление меню и пунктов меню]
В идеале хотелось бы сделать `autocomplete` который ищет по полю `name` по всем моделям или хотя бы выпадающее меню.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как такое возможно сделать.

`models.py`

```
class Page(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Имя страницы', max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Page'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Pages'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Имя статьи', max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Article'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Articles'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Menu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Имя меню', max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Menu'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Menus'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class MenuItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Имя пункта меню', max_length=50)
    url = models.URLField('Ссылка пункта меню', max_length=200)
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType, limit_choices_to={
        'model__in': (
            'page',
            'article',)
    }, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    obj = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'MenuItem'
        verbose_name_plural = 'MenuItems'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

`admin.py`

```
class MenuItemObjectAdminInLine(admin.StackedInline):
  model = MenuItem
  ct_field = "content_type"
  ct_fk_field = "object_id"
  extra = 0

class MenuAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [MenuItemObjectAdminInLine]

admin.site.register(Menu, MenuAdmin)
```

Comment: Нашел решение через [django-autocomplete-light](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/789067/options-object-has-no-attribute-virtual-fields/789118#789118)

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать самому, можно воспользоваться одним из готовых плагинов (их около десятка, если не больше). Например тот же [Django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/admin/__init__.py)

В вашем случае подойдёт `ForeignKeyAutocompleteStackedInline`

Дока: http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin_extensions.html

Comment: Могли бы вы продемонстрировать пример на моих моделях и связях?

Comment: @AleksGrek на данный момент не имею возможности развернуть джанго и протестировать, к сожалению. Может позже появится время, тогда попробую.