# 'Options' object has no attribute 'virtual_fields'

Tags: django, django-admin, autocomplete

Привет.

Попытался воспользоваться примером [django-autocomplete-light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/gfk.html)

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models


class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Page(CommonInfo):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Page'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Pages'


class Article(CommonInfo):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Article'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Article'


class Menu(CommonInfo):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Menu'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Menus'


class MenuItem(CommonInfo):

    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        editable=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        editable=False,
    )

    location = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Menu'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Menus'
```

views.py

```
from dal_select2_queryset_sequence.views import Select2QuerySetSequenceView

from queryset_sequence import QuerySetSequence

from .models import Page, Article


class LocationAutocompleteView(Select2QuerySetSequenceView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        page = Page.objects.all()
        article = Article.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            page = page.filter(title__icontains=self.q)
            article = article.filter(title__icontains=self.q)

        # Aggregate querysets
        qs = QuerySetSequence(page, article)

        if self.q:
            # This would apply the filter on all the querysets
            qs = qs.filter(title__icontains=self.q)

        # This will limit each queryset so that they show an equal number
        # of results.
        qs = self.mixup_querysets(qs)

        return qs
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from app.views import LocationAutocompleteView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(
        'location-autocomplete/',
        LocationAutocompleteView.as_view(),
        name='location-autocomplete'
    ),
]
```

forms.py

```
from dal import autocomplete
from dal_queryset_sequence.fields import QuerySetSequenceModelField
from dal_select2_queryset_sequence.widgets import QuerySetSequenceSelect2
from .models import Page, Article, MenuItem


class MenuItemForm(autocomplete.FutureModelForm):
    location = QuerySetSequenceModelField(
        queryset=autocomplete.QuerySetSequence(
            Page.objects.all(),
            Article.objects.all(),
        ),
        required=False,
        widget=QuerySetSequenceSelect2('location-autocomplete'),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MenuItem
        fields = ('title', 'location', )
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Menu, MenuItem
from .forms import MenuItemForm, Page, Article


class MenuItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MenuItem
    form = MenuItemForm


class MenuAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        MenuItemInline,
    ]


admin.site.register(Menu, MenuAdmin)
admin.site.register(Page)
admin.site.register(Article)
```

В админке при заполнении все работает [image: django autocomplete admin]

При сохранении выдает ошибку `'Options' object has no attribute 'virtual_fields'` [image: 'Options' object has no attribute 'virtual_fields']

Answer (score -2):

Обновил `django-autocomplete-light` все заработало

Comment: При установке pip install django-autocomplete-light ставится не совместимая с django 2.0 версия. Можно установить `pip install -e git+https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light.git#egg=django-autocomplete-light` и тогда закачается версия с git